# Nested infinity recyclerview like reddit in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a feature like Reddit that all comments get into the parent comments. It worked, but I don't know why it gives an output of all nested comments in the last comment, which is fetched from the firebase database.

refer to this img for how I am getting output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9QRT.png)

work:
I have implemented one recyclerView in mainActivity and another in sample_layout for each item of parent RecyclerView.

My code of parentAdapter is:

```
public class commentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<commentsAdapter.MyHolder> {

    ArrayList<commentsModel> list;
    ArrayList<commentsModel> listKey;
    Context context;

    ArrayList<commentsModel> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<commentsModel> listKey2 = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    commentsAdapter adapter;

    //
    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool
            viewPool
            = new RecyclerView
            .RecycledViewPool();
    //

    public commentsAdapter(ArrayList<commentsModel> list, ArrayList<commentsModel> listKey, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.listKey = listKey;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_comment, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

        commentsModel adp = list.get(position);
        commentsModel adp2 = listKey.get(position);

        holder.profileName.setText(adp.getName());
        holder.points.setText(adp.getPoints());
        holder.postedTime.setText(adp.getTime());
        Glide.with(context).load(adp.getImg()).into(holder.profileImg);

        //instances
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        //Set the inner Recyclerview with adapter
        adapter = new commentsAdapter(list2, listKey2, context);
        holder.innerRes.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(
                holder.innerRes.getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false);
        holder.innerRes.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        holder.innerRes.setHasFixedSize(true);
       holder.innerRes.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);

        String path = adp2.getPath();

        //Fetch the data from database to populate the recycler view via model
        mDatabase.getReference().child(path).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    commentsModel adp = snapshot1.getValue(commentsModel.class);
                    list2.add(adp);


                    String path2 = snapshot1.getKey();
                    String fullPath = path + "/" + path2 + "/Comments";

                    commentsModel adp2 = new commentsModel(fullPath);
                    listKey2.add(adp2);

                }


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView profileName, postedTime, points;
        ShapeableImageView profileImg;
        RecyclerView innerRes;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profileName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
            postedTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postedTime);
            profileImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImg);
            points = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points);
            innerRes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerRec);
        }
    }
}
```

As I told it gives all inner comments in the last comment of topMost parent recyclerView.

Comment: why u create an instance of firebase database in onBindViewHolder func? I think it will create a lot of instance of firebase database equivalent to the number of items u have, additional, how do u unregister listen firebase database?

Comment: @baonq-2356 then how can I print infinity times nested comments?

Comment: it is not main issue of u, but i think u should create an only instance of firebase database inside your adapter, then u can register listenter for child each in onBindViewHolder with the child key get from adp2.getPath(). It will help u reduce storage of app when runtime

Comment: @baonq-2356 ya, now I am passing instance of FirebaseDatabase in adapter constructor with context.

Comment: ok, or u can create it inside adapter body, such as: FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Comment: An adapter shouldn't load data. It should only display already loaded data. I would fix the architecture first.